# What is the fastest algorithm for this kind of RMQ?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, rmq

I am doing a task using the following algorithm (pseudo code)

```
int A = []
int C = { ... } // N non-negative integers 
int R = { ... } // N non-negative integers
for(i = 0 to N){
    // Let j in range [i-R[i], i-1]
    A[i] = Minimum of ( A[j] + C[j] ) where j in [i-R[i], i-1]
}
```

What the loop trying to do is, use a range of previous computed `A[j]` to compute current `A[i]`.

To me it is like doing N dynamic RMQs (Range minimum query).

It is dynamic because we do not know the value of `A` beforehand, we compute it online using the previously computed values.

---

For example,

```
C = {10,1,5,3}
R = {2,4,2,3}

A[0] = C[0] // Assume for i = 0, this is always true as base case
A[1] = Min(A[j] + C[j]) where -3 <= j <= 0, only j = 0 is valid option
     = Min(A[0] + C[0]) = 20
A[2] = Min(A[j] + C[j]) where 1 <= j <= 1
     = 21
A[3] = Min(A[j] + C[j]) where -1 <= j <= 2
     = Min(A[0]+C[0], A[1]+C[1], A[2]+C[2])
     = Min(20, 21, 24)
     = 20
```

---

So my question is, is there any algorithm which is faster than `O(N^2)` to achieve this? I feel like there is some method / data structure to speed up the `N` RMQs, but I do not know how.

Please tell me to elaborate more if the example is not clear.

Comment: Your example has a bug. When i = 2, i - R[i] = 2 - 2 = 0, therefore the range of J should be 0 to 1 instead of 1 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic RMQ problem is a basic application of [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), with complexity `O(log n)` per query.